# Can I ask questions regarding Samsung's SmartAppDeveloper Challenge registration on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, scope

Before I post a question on a topic, I wish to ask if it's allowed.

I am trying to register for [Samsung Smartapp Developer Challenge](http://developer.samsung.com/challenge/2012.do). The support of Samsung has no clue on how registration is to happen, nor do they have any meaningful FAQ. It's a pain and I am wondering if anyone else has similar issues and how they have overcome it.

I am asking if it's ok to ask on Stack Overflow, I will *not* ask if it does not make sense.

Comment: No, I don't think asking how to register into any event is on topic on any Stack Exchange site. We are not some kind of "global support" service. :)

Comment: are you talking about [Samsung Developer Challenge](http://developer.samsung.com/challenge/2012.do) ?

Comment: "Dont downvote the hell out of me here".... tempting.... ;)

Comment: @Lucifer yes it is the same.

Comment: Its in korean language, are you able to read the details ?

Comment: Lets not discuss it. Its not allowed, and I am not interested in getting downvoted. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question is definitely off topic for Stack Overflow.

It *might* be OK for [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/), however it doesn't sound like the site is a web application in the sense that we use in our definition (an interactive site with dynamic content) which makes it off topic there as well.

However I would suggest that your first port of call should be Samsung. There **must** be some contact details somewhere on the site.

Comment: thanks. I wont be asking that question.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe this would be on topic on any SE site. it would qualify as Too Localized even if it were on topic, though.